# Django REST Framework testing: How to pass parameters to POST request. Getting error 400 instead of 201

Tags: unit-testing, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-400

The articles are created by admin. The authenticated user has the right to read them and to Like them or Unlike them. I need to test the view.

The model is:

```py
class Like(models.Model):
    reader = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

The view is as follows (the user should not pass any params - he "likes" the article and a new registry is created based on his id and the article id):

```py
class LikeCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Like.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer
```

The test class is:

```py
class TestLikeViews(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='Name', email='test@company.com', password='top_secret')  
        self.article = Article.objects.create(
            author='X', title='Title', body='Body content...')
        self.like = Like.objects.create(
            reader=self.user, article=self.article)

    def test_like_post_user(self):
        request = self.factory.post('likes/', kwargs={'reader': self.user, 'article': self.article}) 
        request.user = self.user 
        response = LikeCreate.as_view()(request, reader=self.user, article=self.article)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201, 
                        f'Expected Response Code 201 - CREATED, received {response.status_code} instead.')
```

I get the following error:

```py
line 105, in test_like_post_user
    f'Expected Response Code 201 - CREATED, received {response.status_code} instead.')
AssertionError: 400 != 201 : Expected Response Code 201 - CREATED, received 400 instead.
```

Line 105 is the line with the f-string - the last line. However, when I start the server and check this endpoint manually - everything works just fine. I suppose the problem lies in the way I formulated the test function.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may rely in the way that you handle the call to the post function, where you have the *kwargs* sent as named argument. This line instead should be fine, also passing just the PKs and not the whole object:

```
request = self.factory.post('likes/', {'reader': self.user.pk, 'article': self.article.pk})
```

That is the usual structure the class **APIRequestFactory** handles requests.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, it does not help. I use the same notation (with "kwargs") in other functions, and it works. But when I try to follow your suggestion, I get `TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Hello @Irina, could you further explain your problem and manual testing methodologies? You said it works perfectly that way. In the meantime, I modified the answer, trying other possible approach, I hope it helps you in any way.